# Onclick display of class elements not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, onclick, helper

I'm trying to get descriptions of acronyms (`tag===p`) to display when I press the button (`tag===button`):

```js
function myFunction() {
  for (let i = 0; i > x.length; i++) {

    var x = [];
    x.push(document.getElementsByClassName("toggleAcronym"));
    for (let j = 0; j > x.length; j++)
      if (x[i][j].style.display === "none") {
        x[i][j].style.display = "block";
      }
  }
}
```

```css
#p6Acronyms {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.toggleAcronym {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>
<html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Intellectual Principles</title>
  <meta name="description" content="sats">
  <meta name="author" content="satser">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Principles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Principles.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="p6Acronyms">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">RWE</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Real World Example</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">CRUD</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Create, Read, Update, Delete</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">CNS</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Central Nervous System</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">MPS</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Muscle Protein Synthesis</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">I.e.</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">In essence</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">ALAP</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">As Long As Possible</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">AMAP</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">As Much As Possible</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">CoC</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Contents of Consciousness</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">RR(P)(F)-R</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Risk Reward (Probability)(Fragility) - Ratio</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">AoL</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Area of Life (=Intellectual, Physical, Relationships & Intellectual)</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">MBS</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Mind Body & Spirit</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">QoC</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Quality of Consciousness</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">PFC</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Pre-Frontal Cortex</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">SRV</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Survival & Reproduction Value. //(Often used to describe factors directional effect on this.)</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">P/T-R</button>
    <p class="toggleAcronym">Practice/Theory-Ratio</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I suspect the JS is incorrect but can't figure out how to get it right. I don't know how to push every element of a certain class to an array and then for every element in that array, if button is clicked, display paragraph. I'm new to JavaScript and don't understand what to do with this error message:

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

, thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to define variable x in this line `for (let i=0; i>x.length; i++) {` but you have an x variable already in this line `var x=[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to toggle the texts of the paragraphs, you don't need an array. You could pass `this` to `myFunction(this)`. Then in the function, toggle the `display` of the `nextSibling` which is the paragraph:

```js
function myFunction(elm) {
  var display = elm.nextSibling.style.display;
  if (display === "none" || display === "") {
    elm.nextSibling.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    elm.nextSibling.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#p6Acronyms {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.toggleAcronym {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="p6Acronyms">
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">RWE</button><p class="toggleAcronym">Real World Example</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">CRUD</button><p class="toggleAcronym">Create, Read, Update, Delete</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">CNS</button><p class="toggleAcronym">Central Nervous System</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">MPS</button><p class="toggleAcronym">Muscle Protein Synthesis</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">I.e.</button><p class="toggleAcronym">In essence</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">ALAP</button><p class="toggleAcronym">As Long As Possible</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">AMAP</button><p class="toggleAcronym">As Much As Possible</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">CoC</button><p class="toggleAcronym">Contents of Consciousness</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">RR(P)(F)-R</button><p class="toggleAcronym">Risk Reward (Probability)(Fragility) - Ratio</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">AoL</button><p class="toggleAcronym">Area of Life (=Intellectual, Physical, Relationships & Intellectual)</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">MBS</button><p class="toggleAcronym">Mind Body & Spirit</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">QoC</button><p class="toggleAcronym">Quality of Consciousness</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">PFC</button><p class="toggleAcronym">Pre-Frontal Cortex</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">SRV</button><p class="toggleAcronym">Survival & Reproduction Value. //(Often used to describe factors directional effect on this.)</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">P/T-R</button><p class="toggleAcronym">Practice/Theory-Ratio</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code does not run with error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined"

Comment: Great, thank you, hadn't used "this" as a funcion argument like that, very helpful.

Comment: @Ronnlidd You are welcome. If this answer helped you solving your problem, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Add id with each paragraph and pass that id to the myFunction()

```
<button onclick="myFunction('RWE')">RWE</button><p id="RWE" class="toggleAcronym">Real World Example</p>
```

and in myFunction

```
    function myFunction(x) {
               if(document.getElementById(x).style.display === "block"){

                   document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none";
              }else{

                document.getElementById(x).style.display = "block";
              }
}
```

works perfect i tried it

Comment: Thanks, I prefer The Fourth Birds' answer due to more readable code.